# Sum of vector elements with a condition in R

Tags: r, vector

I want to calculate the sum of the elements of my vector and stop the sum when we exceed the value of 0.8. Then show the first elements that served to the sum.

Thanks.

Comment: Stop before or after reaching 0.8?

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on @akrun's answer.

A tidyverse solution might look like:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> #load your data
> a <- c(0.23076923, 0.21457490, 0.15384615, 0.13765182, 0.10931174, 0.10931174, 0.03238866, 0.01214575)
> a
[1] 0.23076923 0.21457490 0.15384615 0.13765182 0.10931174 0.10931174 0.03238866 0.01214575


> a %>%
as_tibble() %>%
mutate("cumsum" = cumsum(value)) %>%
filter(cumsum <= 0.8)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
      value    cumsum
      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 0.2307692 0.2307692
2 0.2145749 0.4453441
3 0.1538461 0.5991903
4 0.1376518 0.7368421
```

I have put your vector into a data frame (a tibble in tidyverse terminology) and added a separate column for the running total.  The filter excludes the values that do not meet your criteria.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much !! it's even better from what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cumsum` to create a logical index to subset the elements where the sum is less than or equal to 0.8 and get the `sum` of those elements

```
a1 <- a[cumsum(a)<= 0.8]
sum(a1)
#[1] 0.7368421
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :), this is the first part of my question, i want also the elements that served the sum ?

Comment: @AdelElOuali Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
a <- c(0.23076923, 0.21457490, 0.15384615, 0.13765182, 0.10931174, 
       0.10931174, 0.03238866, 0.01214575)
```

You subset the vector, `a`, using a logical index vector: `cumsum(a) < 0.8`

```
a[cumsum(a) < 0.8]
# [1] 0.2307692 0.2145749 0.1538461 0.1376518
```